# Reversing an Array, Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, reverse

Am VERY new to python. No access currently to teachers, trying to teach myself using HackerRank. I realise this is quite a straightforward problem but...

Currently solving a problem that reverses an array from either a user input, or set input (i.e., 4 integers).

This is my code so far:

```
elements = [input("Enter an int: ") for i in range(4)]

arr = []

array = arr.append(elements)

print(arr)
```

My first question:
I don't understand conceptually why "print(array)" results in None rather than printing out the entire array sequence. I realise that arr.append, stores the input in arr, but why doesn't it recognise storing the entire thing in the new variable array.

I am trying to reverse the array so that [1, 2, 3, 4] becomes [4, 3, 2, 1] however the reversed function., i.,e,

```
print(reversed(arr))
```

doesn't work. Neither does:

```
a = arr.reverse()
print(a)
```

This just outputs None, not sure why.

Also, the word list and array (which I had believed to be more like a matrix) seems to be used by people interchangeably, but I had believed they are quite conceptually different??

Comment: you can use arr[::-1] to reverse an array

Comment: That print statement won't output none, you assign the append to a different variable that you never attempt to print, the print statement you print here will print something out

Comment: 1.) not all functions return something, some modify the given parameter in place. `append()` is a member function of the list class, it modifies the list-instance you call it with. **All** function calls in python return something - if the do not return anything explicitly, they return `None` - hence where the `None` comes from: its the return of the `arr.append(elements)` which modifies `arr` "in place" and returns nothing --> `None`.

Comment: 2.) HackerRank can be used as additional resource to learn pyhton and make it more fun - NOT as sole ressource - look for python tutorials to learn the basics, especially if you are new to programming. Start with https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ and then google more..

Comment: 3.) Any question should you lead you first to duckduck/google/bing (`site:python.org list.append`) , and then to the API documentation of python and its modules, 99.99% of your questions will be ansered there: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html  - if the function _returns_ something it will be mentioned there, else it does not.

Comment: @Patrick Artner. I appreciate that. I don't use HackerRank as a source of information, more as a source of puzzles, since with coding, I seem to learn a lot better by trying to solve puzzles. A lot of the documentation explains things, but sometimes I don't comprehend the exact meaning of the examples they use unless I've dealt with it by doing.

Comment: @PatrickArtner This is what I have now: elements = [input("Enter an int: ") for i in range(4)]

print(elements)

my_list = list(elements)

print(*my_list[::-1], sep=", ") #*Unpacks the list and prints them in a non-list format.

I realise too now that elements is storing it in a list already, so my_list is kind of unnecessary code. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

instead of print(reversed(arr)) this line you have set a new variable name
for ex,
     new_arr=reversed(arr)
     print(list(new_arr))

Comment: You are creating a list of list [[1,2,3,4]] so, if you reverse this you will get same list as a output.


```
elements = [input("Enter an int: ") for i in range(4)]

arr = []

arr.append(elements)

print(arr)

reversed_array = list(reversed(arr[0]))

print(reversed_array)

```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realise the first line, with inputs, stores everything in a list.

Answer (score 0):

You append whole „elements” array to the first element of `arr` array, so the latter has only one element - reversed one-element array is the same as the original one.

Comment: Okay thanks! I didn't realise the elements variable was storing the input as a list already. I had never come across that before.

Answer (score 0):

you are appending one list to another list and "list1.append(1)" doesn't return anything ,it just append one in list list1.hence when you do "list2 = list1.append(1)" nothing gets returned from this which should get saved in list2 .
In python if a method doesn't return anything is returns None as default, hence you get None as output in list2.
for reversing an array you can use below code.

elements = [input("Enter an int: ") for i in range(4)]

print(arr[::-1])

Comment: Thanks, exceedingly helpful. I didn't realise that elements variable was storing as a list itself. It's the first time I used the way of storing inputs.